# Use the path as an argument in shell file from python

Tags: python, shell

I want to call from python a shell script which contain the running of another python function. I would like to use for that subprocess method. My code so far look like:

```
arguments = ["./my_shell.sh", path]
ret_val = subprocess.Popen(arguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

while the script is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ... 
python -c "from file import method; 
method()"
```

How can I give in the directory (to cd) of the path that I pass as an argument in the shell file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your arguments as `$1`, `$2`, etc. So your `cd` command would simply be `cd $1`.